# Conditional regexp replacement in ant

Tags: regex, ant

I have an XML processing framework in ant, need to replace *some* entity references based on a mapping file. I formatted the mapping file as a property file with entries:

oldname=newname

I was thinking about using ReplaceRegExp like this:

```
    <replaceregexp
    match="&amp;(e-[^;]+);" //find entity refs
    replace="&amp;${\1};" //replace with matched property value (but only if property exists)
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to implement the condition, and replacement value doesn't resolve the property value.

I'll probably implement a custom ant task in Java. If anybody knows a clever way to achieve this in ant/contrib only, I'd like to see it! I looked at copy/filterchain, but it seems to use the same regexp functionality. Then there's `<script>`, but that's almost like writing a custom task anyway.

Comment: This doesn't completely solve your problem, but in `replace="&amp;${\1};"`, Ant interprets `${\1}` as an Ant property reference. To not have Ant try to find a property literally named `\1`, escape the dollar sign: `replace="&amp;$${\1};"` See [$$ Expansion](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for a hint, Chad, I wasn't aware of the $$ expansion. However, my understanding based on the linked doc is that $$ will actually suppress property expansion. Indeed, a simple test `<echo>$${oldname}=${oldname}</echo>` produces `${oldname}=newname`. ReplaceRegExp output is identical with $ and $$ which seems to confirm that `replace` attribute isn't expanded.